# Polynomial Bound of Trace of a $n \times n$ matrix $T^m$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider an $n × n$ binary matrix $T$ (all entries are either $0$
or $1$). Assume at most $0.01n^2$ of the entries of $T$ are zero.

Find a  positive constant $c<1$ such that: for integers
$m ≥ 2$, the trace of $T^m$ is at least $(cn)^m$.

N.B $T$ can have trace at most $n$. Can we say $T^m$ have trace at most $n^m$?
How to use the fact for any $n$ "at most $0.01n^2$ of the entries of $T$ are zero"? I see that for $n\le 9$ the matrix $T$ has only entries $1$.

Comment: Problem M5 of the [PRIMES 2017 problem set](http://math.mit.edu/research/highschool/primes/materials/2017/entpro2017usa.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT. The question is interesting but I do not know how to do...

Let $\alpha=n/100$. We consider the worst case when the number of $0$ in $T$ is $n\alpha$ and $\alpha$ is an integer. In these conditions, a bad case is when $\alpha$ rows of $T$ are $0$; for such a matrix $T_0$,  $tr(T_0^k)=(n-\alpha)^k=(99/100)^kn^k$. Consequently, $c\leq 0.99$.

I have instances, with $n=100$, that show that $c\leq 0.989898$.

Proposition. For such a matrix $T$, $trace(T^2)\geq 0.98 n^2\approx (0.98995 n)^2$.

Proof. Let $U$ be the matrix of ones and $T=U+H$; since the entries of $H$ are $\leq 0$, the entries of $H^2$ are $\geq 0$. $tr(T^2)=tr(U^2)+tr(H^2)+2tr(UH)\geq tr(U^2)+2tr(UH)=n^2+2\sum_{i,j}h_{i,j}$ and $tr(T^2)\geq n^2-2n^2/100$.  $\square$

PS. The easily provable fact that $tr(T^k)\leq n^k$ is your business.

Comment: your argument wont work when $m>100$.

Comment: Of course, it works if $\alpha$ is an integer (and not $n\alpha$; edited above) and for any $k$. Anyway,  the bound for $c$ is $<0.99$ and even $<0.989898$ (edited above); clearly, the first reasoning is indicative only. Moreover, the people who asked the question (your supervisor ?) seems to want for $c$ a bound that is valid for any $n$ and $k$; since I give a majorant of $c$, the fact that $k>100$ is useless. On the other hand, it would be interesting that you tell us what you've found ...